# Why is there a "new" in Go?

Tags: go

I'm still puzzled as why we have `new` in Go.

When you want to instantiate a struct, you do

```
t := Thing{}
```

and you can get a pointer to a new instance by doing

```
t := &Thing{}
```

But there's also this possibility :

```
t := new(Thing)
```

This last one seems a little alien to the rest of the language. `&Thing{}` is as clear and concise as `new(Thing)` and it uses only constructs you often use elsewhere. It's also more extensible as you might change it to `&Thing{3}` or  `&Thing{Feets:7}`.

In my opinion, having a supplementary keyword<sup>1</sup> is costly, it makes the language more complex and adds to what you must know. And it might mask to newcomers what's behind instantiating a struct.

It also makes one more reserved word.

So what's the reasoning behind `new` ? Is it sometimes useful ? Should we use it ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> : Yes, I know it's not a keyword at the grammar level, [you can shadow it](http://play.golang.org/p/1fPPqcXNU1), but that doesn't change the fact it's, for the reasonable developer, a reserved word.</sub>

Comment: legacy from java/C++?

Comment: Probably. But does that sound as an error to have kept it only to me ?

Comment: "...to Go coders..." - this is the reason. F#/Haskell/etc. are very alien to C developers and that's why they are getting ~0 traction. Scala made an effort and now it is more approachable and heard of.

Comment: By the same notion, Python and Ruby are very alien to C developers, as they use bunch of unfamiliar keywords, "weird" syntactical rules (where are braces?) and strange semantical concepts (generators? metaclasses? decorators?). Yet they don't get ~0 traction, quite the opposite.

Comment: @Xion: did you look at the initial growth rate of Ruby? It took *ages* to get where it is now (18 years, to be precise). Python is even older (1991!).

Comment: Another possibility may be that they originally went with `new` because of the impler parsing semantics for the compiler toolchain.

Comment: @Den This is likely to change in the future, but Scala isn't particularly popular yet, and in particular [not more popular or "heard of" than Haskell](http://langpop.com/). Scala can also be very weird looking to Java programmers, and in fact in the early days some complained precisely about that: that Scala was "too difficult" for real world use (an assertion I don't agree with, either for Scala or for pure FP languages).

Comment: @AndresF. Some of the resistance to Scala could have nothing to do with the language.  As a younger programmer (age 25), something about the name itself makes me think of a cross between a math-based language like Matlab (which I have bad memories of) and a really old one like Fortran.  There has never been any urge to even look at it.

Comment: The best answer would surely come from the people who invented the language.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Feel free to invite them here ;)

Comment: @AndresF. I don't have the numbers but I'd wager Scala sees more industry use by large scale companies than Haskell.

Comment: @Rig Agreed. Scala is more likely to be adopted by the industry (besides well known cases such as Twitter, where I work is also starting to use Scala as well, though with mixed results). But this is likely because Scala is a JVM language which interoperates with Java nicely, and not because it's "less alien to C programmers". To C/Java programmers, Scala can look truly bizarre. I remember there used to be plenty of complaints about this some years ago.

Comment: @AndresF. The JVM is a big reason, from what I understand, why my division is migrating towards it. Its already used in other divisions. I have to say our ramp up was fairly short with a largely .NET and Java developer base.

Comment: A side note: *new* isn't a keyword in Go. It's a built-in function.

Comment: @ManishMalik Good observation but unless [you shadow it](http://play.golang.org/p/1fPPqcXNU1), this makes little difference to me. I'd still call it a keyword even if it's not implemented at the grammar level

Comment: @Izkata: That's a great shame, because Scala is one of the most modern and expressive languages I've had the pleasure to use.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/K3Ys8qpml2Y

Comment: Ruby was virtually unknown in the English-speaking world until Ruby on Rails came onto the scene, ~10 years after Ruby was created.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The best way to ask is probably to the people working on it; exactly what [I did](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/K3Ys8qpml2Y)!

**Tl;dr: it was originally there before `make` and `&{}`, and it's still the function to use in some situations.**

Basically, here are the most important parts quoted:

> > So what's the reasoning behind new ? Is it something useful ? Should we 
> >     use it ?
>
> You cannot do this without new

```
v := new(int)
*v++
fmt.Println(*v)
```

> new isn't a headline feature of Go, you won't find it used often, but 
>   when you need it, it is there.
>
> Cheers
>
> Dave

After another answer showing this kind of solution:

```
vv := 0
v := &vv
*v++
fmt.Println(*v)
```

I asked for further clarification:

> > So basically, Dave's point doesn't really stand?
>
> There are places where it's inconvenient to sneak in a new
>   variable just to take its address.
>
> new(T) has an immediately straightforward meaning, rather than
>   being a multi-step idiom.
>
> Dave's point only falls if mere technical possibility (of doing without
>   `new`) is compelling on its own.
>
> > Wasn't this discussed because it was just obvious that Go should have it because almost every language has it?
>
> The "shall we keep `new`?" discussion pops up from time to time.
>   Since we can't take it out until Go 2, if I understand the Promise correctly,
>   there doesn't seem to be much to be had from going round the
>   loop again; by the time Go 2 is thinkaboutable, we might have some
>   different and better ideas ...
>
> Chris

It's also there mostly for historical reasons:

> > you need to consider the history of the project. i think new is introduced
> >     first before there is make.
>
> That is true.  In fact we struggled for a while before coming up with
>   the idea of make.  If you look at the repository logs you can see that
>   make only shows up in January 2009, revision 9a924177598f.
>
> The new builtin function also preceded the idea of &{} for taking the
>   address of a composite literal (and that syntax is in some sense
>   wrong; it probably ought to be (*T){fields of T} but there wasn't
>   enough reason to change it).
>
> The new function is not strictly necessary but code does seem to use
>   it in practice.  It's hard to get rid of it at this point.
>
> Ian

Comment: I would be happy to see links to the other *"shall we keep new?" discussions* which *pops up from time to time*.

Comment: Does something prevent you from doing `v := &(0)` and skipping the temp variable? (I know no Go.)

Comment: @AlexFeinman As `0` is a literal constant, you can't take its address. A problem would occur if you'd want a specific type too. That's why a syntax like `&int` or `&int(0)` might be useful (didn't think a lot about the best syntax, though). But doing it in two lines as Collins showed is fine too (`vv := 0; v := &vv`).

Comment: "Since we can't take it out until Go 2" ...which, as everyone knows, will never happen because `Go 2` is considered harmful.

Comment: @MasonWheeler you almost killed me... still laughing at "Go 2 considered harmful"... weirdly enough I was talking about that article today at lunch.

Comment: Rather than wait for Go 2, why not add a strict switch that forbids all unneeded nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

In peano.go they do the following:

```
type Number *Number
func add1(x *Number) *Number  {
     e := new(Number)
     *e = x
     return e
}
```

and I could rewrite it without using "new" and get the same results:

```
type Number *Number
func add1(x *Number) *Number {
     var e Number
     e = x
     return &e
}
```

So even in this very particular case, it does not seem necessary at all.

Comment: run `go build -cflags "-m"` and I believe you'll see why they chose their solution. If it needs to be more obvious https://gist.github.com/Lewiscowles1986/df2e49ebafd51f74f1d3331736607dd4/revisions shows the 2 line diff. This can be why unit analysis fails